# Matlab Image Processing Color Reduction

Tags: image, matlab

I recently asked a question about using matlab to reduce the number of colors in an image. However, when I attempted this, I was only able to get color approximations which then matched the pixel to the nearest color within the color map.

For example, using a color map with only three colors [red, green, blue], it would scan each color and then map either red green or blue. However, this process did not vary the RGB densities to create realistic looking color.

I'm curious if there is any sort of built in function that would use these three colors and vary the density of them to achieve the average color of a certain "pixel field".

I realize this would lose resolution, but I'm essentially trying to make realistic looking images, using only three colors by varying the amounts of RGB within a certain region.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the function [`rgb2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html) and its `'dither'` option.

Comment: I don't believe I am. The rgb2ind essentially maps a certain range of colors to a specific color thus reducing the total number of colors. However, it doesn't seem vary the density of the colors such that the diffused colors represent a wide range of colors. Instead I just get an image that has each pixel scanned, and then set to one of the indexed colors. This would be fine if I had a decent amount of indexed colors, but I'm trying to create realistic looking pictures with colors using only 3 colors, red, green, or blue.

Comment: @Teague are you familiar with [dithering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither)? this is exactly what you are describing.